# при удалении строки из таблицы упорядочить name

Tags: jquery

Есть таблица. В ней есть строка. И есть кнопки добавить строку и удалить строку. Изначально элементы формы в строках таблицы имеют `name`, например `items_1`, `quantity_1` и тд. по кнопке "добавить" добавляется строка в таблицу, а в `name` цифра меняется на следующую, например, `items_2`, `quantity_2`.

Пример тут: [добавление и удаление строк](http://jsfiddle.net/kley/yqx150u0/)

Так вот, при удалении строки,например первой, я хочу чтобы в первой строке  таблицы опять были `name items_1`, `quantity_1`, во второй строке `items_2`, `quantity_2`. Т.е. переписать все индексы по порядку строк.

Я пытаюсь так:

```
 $('tbody tr').find("*[name]").each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name").slice(0,-1) + (i+1)); 
 });
```

но получается обработчик находит каждый `name` и приписывает ему следующий индекс. получается в строке 1: `items_1`, `quantity_2`, `quantity_3`, `price_4`, а надо  в строке 1: `items_1`, `quantity_1`, `quantity_1`, `price_1`. и тд. как задать правильно селектор  или цикл?

Comment: ну так вы перебираете каждый найденные `name`, найдите строку и там уже меняйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('tbody').find("tr").each(function (i) {
    $(this).find("*[name]").each(function (y) {
            $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name").slice(0,-1) + (i+1)); 
    }); 
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw55ubh2/)